# Automatising classification of text via Llama2 in VS Code locally

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, llama

I want to perform a categorisation of multiple articles using Llama2. For this I have downloaded the model locally into my MacBook Pro following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsVZJbnnaSs

It runs well and I can talk with the chatbot of Llama2 7B. What I am trying to do modify the code so that using a **simple prompt**: *does this article describe financial risk? please answer with yes or no and give an explanation*

Let me show you what I have done so far:

1. create a new folder with the input (texts):
   [image]
2. create the prompt in prompt folder:
   [image]
3. create an output folder:
   [image]
4. Running the code in the terminal:

```
for article_file in ./articles/*.txt; do
    output=$(echo -e "\n" | ./main -m ./models/7B/ggml-model-q4_0.bin -n 4096 --repeat_penalty 1.0 --color -i -r "User:" -f "$article_file")
    echo "Article: $article_file" >> ./output/results.txt
    echo "$output" >> ./output/results.txt
    echo "---------------------" >> ./output/results.txt
done
```

5. This is what I get without filling in the output folder:
   [image]

Does any body have any suggestions on what can I do to produce the desire output?

Thanks very much in advance!